# Variables and jquery objects

Tags: jquery

I am using variables to hold jquery objects as

```
$mydiv = $('#somediv');
```

Now I would like to extend this to reference a paragraph within `$mydiv`.  Obviously you could declare a new variable

```
$mypara = $('#somediv p')
```

But is there any way to extend the `$mydiv` variable to find the paragraph it contains.

I just can't figure out the right notation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$mydiv.find('p');
```

Comment: the extra $() is not needed. $mydiv already refers to a jquery object.

Comment: Thanks guys $mydiv.find does the trick.   

Love jquery you seem to be able to do most things - if only you can work out how to construct it!

Pete

Comment: @Jamiec my mistake - wrote it in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.It have.

```
$mydiv = $('#somediv');
$mydiv.find('p');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var = mydiv = $('#somediv');
var children = mydiv.children('p');
```

This will give you all the child 'p' elements belonging to your div.

Comment: your answer is only similar to $('#somediv > p'). It is different with $('#somediv p')